# E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 2608 (packagekitd)

Tags: apt

When I type `sudo apt update` for the first time after opening my laptop, I got this error message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 2608 (packagekitd)
```

But when I type `sudo apt update` again, things are working like normal. I want to know why I get this error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu Software often updates its software database after the user boots Ubuntu for the first time on any day. Ubuntu Software was already updating its software database when you typed `sudo apt update` for the first time after opening your laptop. This put a lock on `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` in order to prevent other applications such as the terminal from using it until the updating process (process 2608) was finished running.

After process 2608 is finished running you can run `sudo apt update` from the terminal without getting a `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` error message.